# Best Redis DataStructure for this usecase

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I have a 2D array with 5000 Rows and 2 Million Columns the value stored is just a boolean 0 or 1. What is the Redis data structure best suited to storing this use-case in Redis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A straightforward approach would be to store the array as a string and use [bit commands](https://redislabs.com/blog/bits-and-bats/) to manipulate it. That should lead to minimal memory use, and [`SETBIT`](https://redis.io/commands/setbit) and [`GETBIT`](https://redis.io/commands/getbit) are both O(1).

If the data could fit in the [512MB limit](https://redis.io/topics/data-types#strings) of a Redis string you could just use a single string. The size you've given is too large, though, so an alternative approach would be to store each row as a separate string.

Comment: sure , SETBIT seems to be interesting, could you please elaborate more on it? Thank you

Comment: That's a great answer but the only problem is that the entire array is 1.5GB and a bitmap can "only" be up to 0.5GB. The resolution can be to have each row of the array a bitmap.

Comment: @ItamarHaber: Thanks, for some reason I thought that limit had been lifted, but [I guess not](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/757). I've updated the answer.

Comment: Not yet lifted, but "soon(tm)" ;P

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can make 5000 databases in a Redis instance, then save each row with the index of the columns which have the value of '1' instead of saving all of the 2 million columns. By doing this, maybe you can reduce the size of each row to half a million length. Then at the time of deserialization, you may build the initial value of array programmatically.

```
//example: row -0 - columns: 00101....1

save [2,4,...,1999999]  // considering zero based indexing
```